# Differentiating between a negative response and lack of response

Tags: survey, polling

Consider a setting where we are trying to determine a set of user's preferences over products. To do so, we present users with ads and keep track of which ads for which products they click on. Over time we can come up with an estimate of what people prefer based on their clicks.

In reality though, the problem seems a bit more complicated than simply presenting ads and recording clicks. It seems users would be less likely to click on an ad, even for a product they like, if we show them too many ads too frequently. This lack of response would then skew our statistics, making us think that they do not like a product, when in reality they have just been overwhelmed with too many ads.

Even though the user's preferences over products didn't change, our advertisement policy influences how much useful feedback we get. We can't simply count clicks, we must account for this "exhaustion" effect as well. Is there any formal way of addressing this?

Comment: Seems like a research paper to me. Not sure if it was already done or not though. You have a better chance in Google Scholar. See this for instance: https://academic.oup.com/jcmc/article/6/3/JCMC636/4584257